# I am getting the following error in Python "list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType"

Tags: python

```
def display_game(games_list):
    print('Here is the current list')
    print(games_list)

display_game(game_list)

def position_choice():
    global choice
    choice= 'Wrong'
      
    while choice not in ['0','1','2']:
        choice = input("Pick a position (0,1,2): ")
        
        if choice not in ['0','1','2']:
            print("sorry, invalid choice! ")
            
            return int(choice)
                        
position_choice()


def replacement_choice(game_list,position):
    user_placement= input('type a string to place in position: ')

    
    game_list[position]= user_placement
    
    return game_list

replacement_choice(game_list,1)


def gameon_choice():
    global choice
    choice= 'Wrong'
      
    while choice not in ['y', '']:
        choice = input("Please pick the option of (Y or N): ")
        
        if choice not in ['y','n']:
            print("sorry, I dont understand. Plese pick Y or N ")
            
        if choice== 'y':
            return True
        else:
            return False
            
                        

gameon_choice()

# here is where I encounter the problem, putting it all together.

game_on= True
game_list= [0,1,2]

while game_on: 
    display_game(game_list)
    
    position = position_choice()
    
    game_list = replacement_choice(game_list,position)
    
    display_game(game_list)
    
    game_on= gameon_choice()
```

Answer (score 0):

see that `position_choice()` is returning None.. move the return outside of the `if choice not in ['0','1','2']` scope

Comment: I am new at coding and python, would you mind showing me an example of what you mean

Answer (score -1):

As per your error message type error so follow the below steps in your code user input get as string you have to convert into an integer

else remove return with int return choice

```
choice=int(input("enter input"))
#chech the varible input type python create automatics data type 
print(type(choice))
print("choice =>",choice)
```

change into your code

```
def position_choice():
    global choice
    choice= 'Wrong'
      
    while choice not in ['0','1','2']:
        #int function use for auto cast value in int
        choice = int(input("Pick a position (0,1,2): "))
        
        if choice not in ['0','1','2']:
            print("sorry, invalid choice! ")
            
            return int(choice)
```

Comment: Do you think after the line 
    **choice = int(input("Pick a position (0,1,2): "))**
will not have any impact on the if condition
    **if choice not in ['0','1','2']:** ???

Comment: That fix the problem. However. if a pick a number, for example 1, This number is wtihin the range in acccordance to the parameter set  in the following line

Comment: if choice not in ['0','1','2']:
            print("sorry, invalid choice! ")

Comment: However, I am still getting the message the i have as an option for whenever the number that is type is not either 0,1 or 2. I dont understand why

Comment: It will actually accept any integer without taking into account the pre set optiuons of 0.1 or 2

Comment: @JD if my answer helps you then please accept an answer and  upvote